# Send parametny from one form to another in C #

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms (C#). In one form, there is a method that takes data and stores them in a database after closing the form that I want to be on the other (the main form) to update the data. How to do it using OOP or simply to make the most beautiful and well.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when you want to let main form to be updated, you create a public method on that form and call it from the other form when it has the new data and can send them to main form. It shouldn't be a problem.

Note that if you want to send data to somewhere, you need a reference to that place, i.e. you need a reference to main form in the other form. Either pass `this` from main form to the constructor of the other form, or you can also store the reference in a static field in `Program` class (do it in `Main` method where you create the main form) etc.

Answer (score 0):

The most OOP-friendly solution would probably be to have an event on whichever form "triggers" a data update, that is subscribed to and handled by another form's method. Here's a basic wire-up:

```
public class Form1:Form
{
   public event EventHandler<MyDataObject> DataChanged;

   ...

   public override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
   {
      //Put in logic to determine whether we should fire the DataChanged event
      try
      {
         if(DataChanged != null) DataChanged(this, myFormCurrentData);
         base.OnClosing(e);
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
         //If any handlers failed, cancel closing the window until the errors
         //are resolved.
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error While Saving", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
         e.Cancel = true;
      }
   }
}

...

public class Form2:Form
{
   //Called from wherever you would open Form1 from Form2
   public void LaunchForm1()
   {
      var form1 = new Form1();
      form1.DataChanged += HandleDataChange;
      form1.Show();
   }

   private void HandleDataChange(object sender, MyDataObject dataObj)
   {
      //Do your data validation or persistence in this method; if it fails,
      //throw a descriptive exception, which will prevent Form1 from closing.
   }
}
```

You don't have to use an event; a simple delegate could be used as well and it would do pretty much the same thing, while also being able to be specified in the form's constructor (thus requiring the handler to be provided).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this for updating the  values in one form from another form...

**Form 2 code**

```
    public event EventHandler<UpdatedEventArgs> updateEvent;

    public class UpdatedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public string SomeVal { get; set; } // create custom event arg for your need
    }

    protected virtual void OnFirstUpdateEvent(UpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (updateEvent != null)
            updateEvent(this, e);
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdatedEventArgs eventData = new UpdatedEventArgs(); 
        eventData.SomeVal = "test"; // set update event arguments, according to your need

        OnFirstUpdateEvent(eventData);
    }

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

**Form 1 code**

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.updateEvent += new EventHandler<Form2.UpdatedEventArgs>(form2_updateEvent); // create event handler to update form 1 from form 2
        form2.Show();
    }

    void form2_updateEvent(object sender, Form2.UpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e != null && e.SomeVal != null)
        {
            // Do the update on Form 1 
            // depend on your event arguments update the grid  
            //MessageBox.Show(e.SomeVal); 
        }

    }
```